# Prevent 2 consecutive commas in a MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, textbox

```
private void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
     && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
     && e.KeyChar != ',')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I have a masked textbox. I only let the user enter numeric values and "," comma.

If the user enters 2 commas consecutively like `,,` I want to remove the last comma.

The user only must enter 1 comma.

For instance:

`TextBox` value is `100,00` if user enters this value like `100,00,,00` I want to change this to `100,00,00`.

How can I delete second comma if 2 commas are consecutively entered in the `KeyPress` event ?

Comment: Could you just do a     `Replace(",,",",")` on the string when you will use it? Otherwise use some logic to keep track of the last entered char

Comment: i need to use it on keypress event

Comment: `if (e.KeyChar == ',' && maskedTextBox1.Text.EndsWith(","))`
?

Comment: What is the mask format for your `MaskedTextBox`?

Comment: You don't need to "delete" the second comma but just prevent it being entered. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // you might also want to check if the textBox1 is empty or whatever else. 
    if (e.KeyChar == ',' && textBox1.Text.EndsWith(",")) 
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
int sequenceCount = 0;
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == ',')
        sequenceCount++;
    else
        sequenceCount = 0;

    if ((!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
    && e.KeyChar != ',') ||  sequenceCount>1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```